# How to use each do in Rails within Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

My HTML looks like:

```
<%= column_chart @data, stacked: true %>
```

In my controller I created the data field:

```
@values = WorkingMonth.select("date_end","workload").where(personal_id: @current_employee.personal_id)
@values.each do |data|
@data = [
    {
    name: "Available",
    data: []
    },
    {
    name: "Workload",
    data:[[data.date_end.strftime("%B"),data.workload]]
    }
]
end
```

My problem is in @values there are more than only one value but it shows me only the last one. How can I use each do with this data field?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I've changed my data field like:

```
@data = @values.map do |value|
@data = [
    {name: "Available", data: []},
    {name: "Workload", data:[[value.date_end.strftime("%B"),value.workload]]}
]
end
```

After changing the result looks like:
[Column Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rYO5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way to think and stopped using .each/.map do. I've used "group" and "DATE_TRUNC". The answer to my problem looks like:

```
@data = [{name: "Workload", data: WorkingMonth.where(personal_id: @current_employee.personal_id).group("DATE_TRUNC('Month', date_end)").sum(:workload)}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `map` instead of `each` since you want convert `@values` array:

```
@data = @values.map do |value|
[
  { name: "Available", data: [] },
  { name: "Workload", data: [[value.date_end.strftime("%B"),value.workload]] }
]
end
```

Comment: I've changed it like you told me but now I have the result [object Object]